# Woocommerce - How To Disable Credit Card Fields Always In One Line?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

On my one page checkout the credit card field is always on one line, even when the Stripe "Inline Credit Card Form" is unchecked.  Is there a setting somewhere to make it multiple fields?

The plugin is the woocommerce plugin

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which plugin did you use?

Comment: Please add screenshots of how it looks now.

Comment: @Bhautik I have added screenshots.  I use the woocommerce plugin.